# How to make a test pending

Tags: testing, clojure, speclj

I am trying to make tests pending in clojure sepclj.

The doc suggest to add `pending` to the characteristics. How is it supposed to be added ?

The following approaches do not produce the expected behavior:

```
(it :pending "should ...")
(it "should ..." :pending)
(pending (it "should ..."))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start from simple spec:

```
(describe "truthiness"
  (it "tests if my-fn returns true"
    (should (my-fn))))
```

To make `(it "tests if my-fn returns true" ...)` characteristic pending:

```
(describe "truthiness"
  (it "tests if my-fn returns true"
    (pending "my-fn should be revisited") ; If message is not specified "Not Yet Implemented" will be used instead
    (should (my-fn))))
```

Comment: I have just noticed `xit` in the doc which makes for a pending test. It is less cumbersome to use than pending.